# Efficient and compact replacement for Association in the following case

Tags: performance-tuning, associations, conditional

Consider the following association:

```
WhatToDo[y_, condition1_, condition2_] := 
 Association[{{y, "True", "False"} -> 
     NIntegrate[
      Exp[-x^y]*Cos[(z + x)^y], {x, 0.1, 5}, {z, 0.2, 7}], {y, "True",
       "True"} -> 
     Max[Table[
       RegionDistance[
        Ball[{0.5, 12, 0.1}, y^i], {y^0.3, y, y^-0.8}], {i, 0.1, 1, 
        0.1}]], {y, "False", "True"} -> 
     ArcTan[1/y], {y, "False", "False"} -> 
     Table[{i, 
       NIntegrate[
        Exp[-x^(y*i)]*Cos[(z + x)^(y*i)], {x, 0.1, 5}, {z, 0.2, 
         7}]}, {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]}][{y, condition1, condition2}]
```

It is stupid since even if fixing any of the arguments it still evaluates for all possible combinations. An ugly alternative would be using `If`, but the code would be very bulky. Could you please tell me what is the analog of `Association` that is compact and simultaneously does not call evaluations for all the possible combinations here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to replace in your Association all `Rule` ("->") with [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) ":>".

Answer (score 2):

You could just overload WhatToDo:

```
WhatToDo2[y_, True, True] := 
  Max[Table[RegionDistance[Ball[{0.5, 12, 0.1}, y^i], {y^0.3, y, y^-0.8}], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]];
WhatToDo2[y_, True, False] := 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-x^y]*Cos[(z + x)^y], {x, 0.1, 5}, {z, 0.2, 7}];
WhatToDo2[y_, False, False] := 
  Table[
    {i, NIntegrate[Exp[-x^(y*i)]*Cos[(z + x)^(y*i)], {x, 0.1, 5}, {z, 0.2, 7}]}, 
    {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
WhatToDo2[y_, False, True] := ArcTan[1/y];
```

(Note, I changed the strings "True"/"False" to just the symbols True/False.)

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to do a similar thing if instead of "True", "False" I would have some generic strings?

Comment: Yes. You could even use a condition to pattern-match on the strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid the overload, a simpler approach than the association is to just use Switch:

```
WhatToDo3[y_, flag1_?BooleanQ, flag2_?BooleanQ] :=
  Switch[
    {flag1, flag2},
    {True, True}, "the Max expression goes here",
    {True, False}, "one of the NIntegrate goes here",
    {False, True}, "the ArcTan goes here",
    {False, False}, "the other NIntegrate goes here"]
```

Or, using strings:

```
WhatToDo4[y_, flag1_String, flag2_String] :=
  Switch[
    {flag1, flag2},
    {"True", "True"}, "the Max expression goes here",
    {"True", "False"}, "one of the NIntegrate goes here",
    {"False", "True"}, "the ArcTan goes here",
    {"False", "False"}, "the other NIntegrate goes here",
    _, "a default would go here"]
```